# 2048-like array shift

Tags: code-golf, array, sliding-puzzle

Assume we want to shift an array like it is done in [the 2048 game](https://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/): if we have two equal consecutive elements in array, merge them into twice the value element.
Shift must return a new array, where every pair of consecutive equal elements is replaced with their sum, and pairs should not intersect. 
Shifting is performed only once, so we don't need to merge resulting values again.
Notice that if we have 3 consecutive equal elements, we have to sum rightmost ones, so for example, `[2, 2, 2]` should become `[2, 4]`, not `[4, 2]`.

The task is to write shortest function which takes an array and returns a shifted array.

You may assume that all integers will be strictly positive.

Examples:

```
[] -> []
[2, 2, 4, 4] -> [4, 8]
[2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 8] -> [2, 4, 8, 8]
[2, 2, 2, 2] -> [4, 4]
[4, 4, 2, 8, 8, 2] -> [8, 2, 16, 2]
[1024, 1024, 512, 512, 256, 256] -> [2048, 1024, 512]
[3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5] -> [3, 6, 2, 7, 10, 10]
```

I am also very interested in solution using reduce :)

Comment: This is a very nice first challenge. Welcome to the site!

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/24589/8478) [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/24134/8478) (There are several other 2048-based challenges, but the merging operation is most important in these two I think.)

Comment: Input is not necessarily sorted and numbers are greater than zero, that is the only restriction on numbers. We may let largest value fit in standard int32 bounds i think. Empty array gives empty array as a result.
Thanks for the participation, appreciate that :)

Comment: To those still voting to close as unclear, the challenge essentially boils down to this: _Assume you have an array of positive integers. Walk through it from end to start. If the current element is equal to the next, replace it with the sum of both and move to the element **after** the replacement, then perform this check again for that element and the next. Repeat until the beginning of the array is reached._

Comment: Is `[4,2,8,8]` valid output for `[2,2,2,4,4,8]`?

Comment: @Titus "Notice that if we have 3 consecutive equal elements, we have to sum rightmost ones, so for example, [2, 2, 2] should become [2, 4], not [4, 2]."

Comment: The ruling on empty arrays is unfortunate; it has invalidated a few answers, including my own.

Comment: I'm guessing APL would be a good language for writing a 2048 game.

Comment: Can we assume that the array length is always even, like in your examples?

Comment: No, it can be odd also. I wonder about an approach in which it will make a difference, could you share? :)

Comment: I think the answers that use string processing rather than an array should be disqualified, unless they first serialise the array, then string process it, then deserialise it again.

Comment: @Joe [Correct](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/87319/43319).

Comment: This might be a little to late, but can you input a reversed list or is the order to be kept the right way?

Answer (score 24):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10 9</s> 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Œg+2/€UF
```

**[TryItOnline](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=xZJnKzIv4oKsVUY&input=&args=WzIsIDIsIDIsIDQsIDQsIDhd)** or **[run all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=xZJnKzIv4oKsVUYKxbzDh-KCrEfigqxq4oG3O-KBt8Kk&input=&args=W1tdLCBbMiwgMiwgMl0sIFsyLCAyLCA0LCA0XSwgWzIsIDIsIDIsIDQsIDQsIDhdLCBbMiwgMiwgMiwgMl0sIFs0LCA0LCAyLCA4LCA4LCAyXSwgWzEwMjQsIDEwMjQsIDUxMiwgNTEyLCAyNTYsIDI1Nl0sIFszLCAzLCAzLCAxLCAxLCA3LCA1LCA1LCA1LCA1XV0)**

#### How?

```
Œg+2/€UF - Main link: a                 e.g. [2,2,2,4,4,8]
Œg       - group runs of equal elements      [[2,2,2],[4,4],[8]]
   2/€   - pairwise reduce for each with
  +      -     addition                      [[4,2],[8],[8]]
      U  - reverse (vectorises)              [[2,4],[8],[8]]
       F - flatten list                      [2,4,8,8]
```

Answer (score 19):

### Haskell, <s>47</s> <s>57</s> 50 bytes

```
e#l|a:b<-l,e==a= -2*a:b|1<2=e:l
map abs.foldr(#)[]
```

Uses `reduce` (or `fold` as it is called in Haskell, here a right-fold `foldr`). Usage example: `map abs.foldr(#)[] $ [2,2,2,4,4,8]` -> `[2,4,8,8]`.

Edit: +10 bytes to make it work for unsorted arrays, too. Merged numbers are inserted as negative values to prevent a second merge. They are corrected by a final  `map abs`.

Comment: The trick with negatives is really nice!

Answer (score 14):

## [Brain-Flak](http://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), <strike>158</strike> 96

```
{({}<>)<>}<>{(({}<>)<><(({})<<>({}<>)>)>)({}[{}]<(())>){((<{}{}>))}{}{{}(<({}{})>)}{}({}<>)<>}<>
```

[Try it online!](http://brain-flak.tryitonline.net/#code=eyh7fTw-KTw-fTw-eygoe308Pik8PjwoKHt9KTw8Pih7fTw-KT4pPikoe31be31dPCgoKSk-KXsoKDx7fXt9PikpfXt9e3t9KDwoe317fSk-KX17fSh7fTw-KTw-fTw-&input=MiAyIDIgNCA0IDg)

**Explanation:**

1 Reverse the list (moving everything to the other stack, but that doesn't matter)

```
{({}<>)<>}<>
{        }   #keep moving numbers until you hit the 0s from an empty stack
 ({}<>)      #pop a number and push it on the other stack
       <>    #go back to the original stack
          <> #after everything has moved, switch stacks
```

2 Do steps 3-6 until there is nothing left on this stack:

```
{                                                                                         }
```

3 Duplicate the top two elements (2 3 -> 2 3 2 3)

```
(({}<>)<><(({})<<>({}<>)>)>)

(({}<>)<>                   #put the top number on the other stack and back on the very top
         <(({})             #put the next number on top after:
               <<>({}<>)>   #copying the original top number back to the first stack
                         )>)
```

4 Put a 1 on top if the top two are equal, a 0 otherwise (from the wiki)

```
({}[{}]<(())>){((<{}{}>))}{}
```

5 If the top two were equal (non-zero on the top) add the next two and push the result

```
{{}(<({}{})>)}{}
{            }   #skip this if there is a 0 on top
 {}              #pop the 1
   (<      >)    #push a 0 after:
     ({}{})      #pop 2 numbers, add them together and push them back on 
              {} #pop off the 0
```

6 Move the top element to the other stack

```
({}<>)<>
```

7 Switch to the other stack and print implicitly

```
<>
```

Comment: pls add comma after language name, otherwise it breaks leaderboard ty :P

Answer (score 9):

## PHP, 116 Bytes

```
<?$r=[];for($c=count($a=$_GET[a]);$c-=$x;)array_unshift($r,(1+($x=$a[--$c]==$a[$c-1]))*$a[$c]);echo json_encode($r);
```

or

```
<?$r=[];for($c=count($a=$_GET[a]);$c--;)$r[]=$a[$c]==$a[$c-1]?2*$a[$c--]:$a[$c];echo json_encode(array_reverse($r));
```

-4 Bytes if the output can be an array `print_r` instead of 'json_encode`

176 Bytes to solve this with a Regex

```
echo preg_replace_callback("#(\d+)(,\\1)+#",function($m){if(($c=substr_count($m[0],$m[1]))%2)$r=$m[1];$r.=str_repeat(",".$m[1]*2,$c/2);return trim($r,",");},join(",",$_GET[a]));
```

Comment: You cannot use sort as the result is not always sorted : [4, 4, 2, 8, 8, 2] -> [8, 2, 16, 2]

Comment: @Crypto You are right after the new test cases has been added. Before the use of sort was okay

Comment: `for($i=count($a=$argv);--$i;)$b[]=($a[$i]==$a[$i-1])?2*$a[$i--]:$a[$i];print_r(array_reverse($b));` same idea but shorter

Comment: @Crypto I'm not sure about the output as string representation or an array. for the testcase `[]` I need `$r=[];` Thank You for your help

Answer (score 9):

## GNU sed, <strike>41 38</strike> 37

Includes +1 for -r
-3 Thanks to [Digital Trauma](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11259/digital-trauma)
-1 Thanks to [seshoumara](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59010/seshoumara)

```
:
s,(.*)(1+) \2\b,\1!\2\2!,
t
y,!, ,
```

Input and output are space separated strings in unary ([based on this consensus](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5349/57100)).

[Try it online!](http://sed.tryitonline.net/#code=OgpzLCguKikoMSspIFwyXGIsXDEhXDJcMiEsCnQKcywhLCAsZw&input=MTEgMTEgMTExMSAxMTExCjExIDExIDExIDExMTEgMTExMSAxMTExMTExMQoxMSAxMSAxMSAxMQ&args=LXI)

Comment: Use `y,!, ,` to save 1 byte.

Comment: @seshoumara Duh... Why didn't I think of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

### Python, 61 bytes

```python
def f(l):b=l[-2:-1]==l[-1:];return l and f(l[:~b])+[l[-1]<<b]
```

The Boolean `b` checks whether the last two elements should collapse by checking that they are equal in a way that's safe for lists of length 1 or 0. The last element if then appended with a multiplier of `1` for equal or `2` for unequal. It's appended to the recursive result on the list with that many elements chopped off the end. Thanks to Dennis for 1 byte!

Comment: `[l[-1]<<b]` saves a byte.

Comment: `l[-2:-1]` is `[l[-2]]`

Comment: I need it to work for lists of size 0 and 1.

Comment: 57 bytes using 3.8 assignment expressions and a lambda https://tio.run/##FcaxCoAgEADQX3FU0iFzkEO/RG5QRAouE3Fp6dcN3/TaO86nHrb1OYuneKccGQGxWDMrnAJ8PIGnoDSoHf3aDihQbGEVnUs4W7/q4IUHI43U0kqLQswf

Answer (score 8):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 32

```
\d+
$*
r`\b\1 (1+)\b
$1$1
1+
$.&
```

`r` on line 3 activates right-to-left regex matching.  And this means that the `\1` reference needs to come before the `(1+)` capturing group that it references.

[Try it online.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=XGQrCiQqCnJgXGJcMSAoMSspXGIKJDEkMQoxKwokLiY&input=MiAyIDQgNAoyIDIgMiA0IDQgOAoyIDIgMiAyCjIgMiAy)

Comment: Nice.. That right-to-left option to match is quite handy! Is it part of .Net regex or a Retina feature?

Comment: I was just about to post mine at 26, using linefeed-separation as the input format: http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShTYCwKLisKJCoKVHJtYMK2YGBeXDHCtigxKykkCiVNYDEKwrYKLA&input=MiwyLDIKMiwyLDQsNAoyLDIsMiw0LDQsOAoyLDIsMiwy the main savings come from that and using transliteration to get rid of the second substitution.

Comment: @Dada It's a .NET feature (and it's used under the hood to enable arbitrary-length lookbehinds). Retina has no unique regex features yet (although it has some unique substitution features).

Comment: @MartinEnder Ok thanks! .NET regex's are really great! *jealous perl coder spotted*

Comment: @MartinEnder I your solution is different enough to warrant another answer

Comment: @DigitalTrauma it's completely the same apart from that one byte saved with the transliteration stage :)

Comment: @Dada hey at least you've got recursion/subroutines ;)

Comment: @MartinEnder yea, there is that... I feel like a combination of .NET and perl could be so great!

Answer (score 8):

## Perl, 41 bytes

Includes +1 for `-p`

Give input sequence on STDIN:

```
shift2048.pl <<< "2 2 2 4 4 8 2"
```

`shift2048.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
s/.*\K\b(\d+) \1\b/2*$1.A/e&&redo;y/A//d
```

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES6), 68 bytes

```js
f=a=>a.reduceRight((p,c)=>(t=p[0],p.splice(0,c==t,c==t?c+t:c),p),[])
    
console.log([
  [],
  [2, 2, 4, 4],
  [2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 8],
  [2, 2, 2, 2],
  [4, 4, 2, 8, 8, 2],
  [1024, 1024, 512, 512, 256, 256],
  [3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5],
].map(f))
```

Comment: Not bad, but according to the executed snippet: `[1024, 1024, 512, 512, 256, 256]` is resolving as `[2048, 512, 1024]` and not `[2048, 1024, 512]`...?

Answer (score 7):

### Perl, 43 + 1 (`-p`) = 44 bytes

Ton Hospel came up with 41 bytes [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95438/55508), check it out!

*-4 thanks to @Ton Hospel!*

**Edit** : added `\b`, as without it it was failing on input like `24 4` on which the output would have been `28`.

```pl
$_=reverse reverse=~s/(\b\d+) \1\b/$1*2/rge
```

Run with `-p` flag :

```
perl -pe '$_=reverse reverse=~s/(\b\d+) \1\b/$1*2/rge' <<< "2 2 2 4 4"
```

I don't see another way than using `reverse` twice to right-fold (as just `s/(\d+) \1/$1*2/ge` would left-fold, i.e `2 2 2` would become `4 2` instead of `2 4`). So 14 bytes lost thanks to `reverse`... Still I think there must be another (better) way (it's perl after all!), let me know if you find it!

Comment: `reverse reverse` seems a bit lengthy. I'm no expert in Perl, but is there a way you can make a shortcut to `reverse` (if nothing else, [ab]using `eval`)?

Comment: Nice sexeger. Notice you can just leave out the `($_)`

Comment: @TonHospel thanks. Indeed, the doc of `reverse` looks like `reverse` can't be called without argument (well the examples show it can be, but there is only one prototype : `reverse LIST`), so I forgot about `$_` being the default argument ;)

Comment: A `LIST` can be  empty...

Comment: @TonHospel indeed, but usually when an operator uses `$_` as default argument, the doc specifies a prototype with no parameters (like `print` or `lenght`...). Or maybe that's just an wrong impression I have.

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>68...64</s>  58 bytes

```javascript
a=>(g=p=>(x=a.pop())|p?p?[...g(p^x?x:!(p*=2)),p]:g(x):a)()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY7NCsIwEITvPkW9ZaVGG/tHIfZBSoVQa1HELFakB9@9ZhMRsbaGyVx25ts9qbtqq@sRb8uL3tf9QfZKblkj0XgnFUeNDOCBOeYF57xhuOvyLpszXEgB4GOZNayDTAGDvtKXVp9rftYNO7CiBPCm32rlFeXsqyZ8zyg0GgNQzczTkeqrTYEBgKpunk4CxJ/d4aDqVgoH/gmgamojQUyBb0KwFobgPArEy0QUWyOevX4dph@pAWXje06BVWJSb7mbiGLmsT0lIRb9sn8C)

#### Commented

```javascript
a => (                  // a[] = input array
  g = p =>              // g is a recursive function taking p = previous value
    (x = a.pop())       //   extract the last entry x from a[]
    | p ?               //   if either x or p is a positive integer:
      p ?               //     if p is a positive integer:
        [               //       update the output:
          ...g(         //         do a recursive call:
            p ^ x ?     //           if p is not equal to x:
              x         //             set new_p = x
            :           //           else:
              !(p *= 2) //             double p and set new_p = false
          ),            //         end of recursive call
          p             //         append p
        ]               //       end of output update
      :                 //     else:
        g(x)            //       do a simple recursive call with new_p = x
    :                   //   else:
      a                 //     stop recursion and return a[], which is guaranteed
                        //     to be an empty array at this point
)()                     // initial call to g with p undefined
```

Comment: I was about to suggest the edit you just made :)

Comment: ``a=>(a.reverse()+'').replace(/(.),\1/g,(c,i)=>i*2).split`,`.reverse()``?

Comment: @l4m2 That does work for single-digit inputs, but would fail on `[1024, 1024, 512, 512, 256, 256]` (I think this test case may have been added later).

Comment: @Arnauld Well yours also fail ...

Comment: ``f=(a,l=[],m)=>(x=a.pop())*!m-l?f(a,x).concat(l):x?f(a,2*x,1):[l]``?

Comment: or ``f=(a,l=[],m)=>m|(x=a.pop())-l?f(a,x).concat(l):x?f(a,2*x,1):[l]``

Answer (score 7):

## Perl 5.10, <s>61</s> 50 bytes (<s>49</s> + 1 for flag)

Thanks to [Ton Hospel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/51507/ton-hospel) for saving 11 bytes!

Regex-free solution, with `-a` flag:

```
@a=($F[-1]-$b?$b:2*pop@F,@a)while$b=pop@F;say"@a"
```

[Try here!](https://ideone.com/1tKnMa)

Comment: Nice alternative method. A pity arrays almost always lose to strings in perl. Still, you can get a bit closer by golfing your code to `@a=($F[-1]-$b?$b:2*pop@F,@a)while$b=pop@F;say"@a"` (50 bytes)

Comment: @TonHospel Indeed, I tend to avoid string-based solutions (just to show that Perl can do more than that!). I don't play to win anyway :D Thanks for the golfing tips!

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 26 bytes

```
D¥__X¸«DgL*ê¥X¸«£vy2ôO})í˜
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=RMKlX19YwrjCq0RnTCrDqsKlWMK4wqvCo3Z5MsO0T30pw63LnA&input=WzIsIDIsIDIsIDQsIDQsIDhd)

**Generalized steps**

1. Reduce by subtraction to find where consecutive elements differ
2. Reduce by subtraction over the indices of those places to find the length of consecutive elements
3. Split input into chunks of those lengths
4. Split chunks into pairs
5. Sum each pair
6. Reverse each summed chunk
7. Flatten to 1-dimensional list

Comment: `DgL` can be `ā` for -2.

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 53 bytes

```
Join@@(Reverse[Plus@@@#~Partition~UpTo@2]&/@Split@#)&
```

## Explanation

```
Split@#
```

Split the input into sublists consisting of runs of identical elements. i.e. `{2, 2, 2, 4, 8, 8}` becomes `{{2, 2, 2}, {4}, {8, 8}}`.

```
#~Partition~UpTo@2
```

Partition each of the sublist into partitions length at most 2. i.e. `{{2, 2, 2}, {4}, {8, 8}}` becomes `{{{2, 2}, {2}}, {{4}}, {{8, 8}}}`.

```
Plus@@@
```

Total each partition. i.e. `{{{2, 2}, {2}}, {{4}}, {{8, 8}}}` becomes `{{4, 2}, {4}, {16}}`.

```
Reverse
```

Reverse the results because Mathematica's `Partition` command goes from left to right, but we want the partitions to be in other direction. i.e. `{{4, 2}, {4}, {16}}` becomes `{{2, 4}, {4}, {16}}`.

```
Join@@
```

Flatten the result. i.e. `{{2, 4}, {4}, {16}}` becomes `{2, 4, 4, 16}`.

Comment: Hi JHM! Thanks for the answer. I don't understand Mathematica very well, so could you add a bit of explanation as to what's going on?

Comment: `Plus@@@` is `Tr/@` and I think you can avoid the parentheses and `Join@@` if you use `##&@@` on the result of `Reverse` (haven't tested it though).

Answer (score 5):

## Haskell, 56 bytes

```
g(a:b:r)|a==b=a+b:g r|l<-b:r=a:g l
g x=x
r=reverse
r.g.r
```

Answer (score 5):

### Java 7, 133 bytes

```
Object f(java.util.ArrayList<Long>a){for(int i=a.size();i-->1;)if(a.get(i)==a.get(i-1)){a.remove(i--);a.set(i,a.get(i)*2);}return a;}
```

Input is an ArrayList, and it just loops backwards, removing and doubling where necessary.

```
Object f(java.util.ArrayList<Long>a){
    for(int i=a.size();i-->1;)
        if(a.get(i)==a.get(i-1)){
            a.remove(i--);
            a.set(i,a.get(i)*2);
        }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: You're comparing `Long` references on line 3 with `==`. Consider `a.get(i)-a.get(i-1)==0`.

Answer (score 4):

## Perl, 37 bytes

Includes +4 for `-0n`

Run with the input as separate lines on STDIN:

```
perl -M5.010 shift2048.pl
2
2
2
4
4
8
2
^D
```

shift2048.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -0n
s/\b(\d+
)(\1|)$//&&do$0|say$1+$2
```

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, <s>86 100 99</s> 94 bytes

```
for($r=[];$v=+($p=array_pop)($a=&$argv);)array_unshift($r,end($a)-$v?$v:2*$p($a));print_r($r);
```

requires PHP 7.0; takes values from command line arguments.

Run with `-nr` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8e345e910aa2254c49fbdcbecb2fbcbb35e3dbb3).

Comment: [2, 2, 2] returns [4,2] instead of [2,4]

Comment: `for($r=[];$v=($p=array_pop)($a=&$_GET[a]);)array_unshift($r,end($a)-$v?$v:2*$p($a));print_r($r);` is 1 Byte shorter

Answer (score 3):

## Julia 205 bytes

```
t(x)=Val{x}
s(x)=t(x)()
f^::t(1)=f
^{y}(f,::t(y))=x->f(((f^s(y-1))(x)))
g()=[]
g{a}(::t(a))=[a]
g{a}(::t(a),B...)=[a;g(B...)]
g{a}(::t(a),::t(a),B...)=[2a;g(B...)]
K(A)=g(s.(A)...)
H(A)=(K^s(length(A)))(A)
```

Function to be called is `H`

eg `H([1,2,2,4,8,2,])`

This is in no way the shortest way do this in julia.
But it is so cool, that I wanted to share it anyway.

- `t(a)` is a value-type, representing the value (a).
- `s(a)` is an instance of that value type
- `g` is a function that dispatches on the difference values (using the value types) and numbers of its parameters. And that is cool
- `K` just wraps `g` so that

Extra cool part:

```
f^::t(1)=f
^{y}(f,::t(y))=x->f(((f^s(y-1))(x)))
```

This defines the `^` operator to apply to functions.
So that `K^s(2)(X)` is same as `K(K(X))`
so `H` is just calling `K` on `K` a bunch of times -- enough times to certainly collapse any nested case

This can be done much much shorter, but this way is just so fun.

Answer (score 3):

### PowerShell v2+, 81 bytes

```
param($n)($b=$n[$n.count..0]-join','-replace'(\d+),\1','($1*2)'|iex)[$b.count..0]
```

Takes input as an explicit array `$n`, reverses it `$n[$n.count..0]`, `-join`s the elements together with a comma, then regex `-replace`s a matching digit pair with the first element, a `*2`, and surrounded in parens. Pipes that result (which for input `@(2,2,4,4)` will look like `(4*2),(2*2)`) over to `iex` (short for `Invoke-Expression` and similar to `eval`), which converts the multiplication into actual numbers. Stores the resulting array into `$b`, encapsulates that in parens to place it on the pipeline, then reverses `$b` with `[$b.count..0]`. Leaves the resulting elements on the pipeline, and output is implicit.

---

#### Test Cases

***NB--*** In PowerShell, the concept of "returning" an empty array is meaningless -- it's converted to `$null` as soon as it leaves scope -- and so it is the equivalent of returning nothing, which is what is done here in the first example (after some wickedly verbose errors). Additionally, the output here is space-separated, as that's the default separator for stringified arrays.

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> @(),@(2,2,4,4),@(2,2,2,4,4,8),@(2,2,2,2),@(4,4,2,8,8,2),@(1024,1024,512,512,256,256),@(3,3,3,1,1,7,5,5,5,5)|%{"$_ --> "+(.\2048-like-array-shift.ps1 $_)}
Invoke-Expression : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Command' because it is an empty string.
At C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing\2048-like-array-shift.ps1:7 char:67
+   param($n)($b=$n[$n.count..0]-join','-replace'(\d+),\1','($1*2)'|iex)[$b.count. ...
+                                                                   ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:String) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand

Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing\2048-like-array-shift.ps1:7 char:13
+   param($n)($b=$n[$n.count..0]-join','-replace'(\d+),\1','($1*2)'|iex)[$b.count. ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

 --> 
2 2 4 4 --> 4 8
2 2 2 4 4 8 --> 2 4 8 8
2 2 2 2 --> 4 4
4 4 2 8 8 2 --> 8 2 16 2
1024 1024 512 512 256 256 --> 2048 1024 512
3 3 3 1 1 7 5 5 5 5 --> 3 6 2 7 10 10
```

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript - 103 bytes

```
v=a=>{l=a.length-1;for(i=0;i<l;i++)a[l-i]==a[l-1-i]?(a[l-i-1]=a[l-i]*2,a.splice(l-i,1)):a=a;return a}
```

Comment: Saved 16 bytes thanks to @MayorMonty tips on [this page](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/tips-for-golfing-in-javascript?page=3&tab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: This doesn't work. Testing with `[2,2,4,4]` yields `[2,2,4,4]`.

Comment: yup. Node v6.2.1

Answer (score 3):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 60 bytes

```
{({}<>)<>}<>{(({}<>)<>[({})]){((<{}>))}{}{({}<>{})(<>)}{}}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/v1qjutbGTtPGDkhWa8A40UCGZqwmUMCmutZOU7O2uhaiECisAVQB5AM5//8bKYCgCRBaAAA)

#### Explanation:

```
{({}<>)<>}<>   Reverse stack

{   While input exists
  (
    ({}<>)   Push copy of last element to the other stack
    <>[({})] And subtract a copy of the next element
  )   Push the difference
  {   If the difference is not 0
    ((<{}>)) Push two zeroes
  }{}  Pop a zero
  {   If the next element is not zero, i.e the identical element
    ({}<>{})  Add the element to the copy of the previous element
    (<>)      Push a zero
  }{}    Pop the zero
}<>  End loop and switch to output stack
```

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 20 bytes

```apl
⌽1⊥¨⌽⊂⍨2|⌽(⊥⍨=)¨,\∘⌽
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HPXsNHXUsPrQAyHnU1PepdYVQDZGoAxYBsW81DK3RiHnXMAAr9T3vUNuFRb9@jvqme/o@6mg@tN37UNhHICw5yBpIhHp7B/9MUHvWu4UpTMNIBIRMggnOgfB0FC0whI2QhIwgfKgNUD0YgIUMDI6AQhDQ1NIISRqZmYAKowFgHigzByByoAo4A)

Fully tacit version of the previous solution, thanks to Adám.

#### How it works

```apl
⌽1⊥¨⌽⊂⍨2|⌽(⊥⍨=)¨,\∘⌽  ⍝ Right argument: V, vector to reduce by 2048 rules
                   ⌽  ⍝ Reverse V to get RV
                ,\∘   ⍝ Prefixes of RV
         ⌽(  =)¨      ⍝ For each prefix, test if each element equals last element
           ⊥⍨         ⍝   and count trailing ones
                      ⍝   (one-based index of each item within runs)
       2|             ⍝ Modulo 2
    ⌽⊂⍨               ⍝ Partition RV at ones of the above
 1⊥¨                  ⍝ Sum of each chunk
⌽                     ⍝ Reverse back
```

---

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 26 bytes

```apl
⌽+/¨{⍵⊂⍨2|{⊥⍨⍵=⊃⌽⍵}¨,\⍵}⌽⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pRz15t/UMrqh/1bn3U1fSod4VRTfWjrqVABlDE9lFXM1ABkFV7aIVODIiGcv@nPWqb8Ki371HfVE9/oKpD640ftU0E8oKDnIFkiIdn8P80hUe9a7jSFIx0QMgEiOAcKF9HwQJTyAhZyAjCh8oA1YMRSMjQwAgoBCFNDY2ghJGpGZgAKjDWgSJDMDIHqoAjAA)

A full program. Link is to function version for easier testing.

#### How it works

```apl
⌽+/¨{⍵⊂⍨2|{⊥⍨⍵=⊃⌽⍵}¨,\⍵}⌽⎕
                         ⎕  ⍝ Take input
                        ⌽   ⍝ Reverse
    {                  }    ⍝ Apply the anonymous function...
                    ,\⍵     ⍝   Prefixes
          {       }¨        ⍝   For each prefix,
             ⍵=⊃⌽⍵          ⍝     Evaluate if each element is equal to last
           ⊥⍨               ⍝     and count trailing ones
                            ⍝     (one-based index of each item within runs)
        2|                  ⍝   Take modulo 2
     ⍵⊂⍨                    ⍝   Partition the input array at 1's of the above
 +/¨                        ⍝ Sum each group
⌽                           ⍝ Reverse back
```

Comment: Go all tacit for [20](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HPXsNHXUsPrQAyHnU1PepdYVQDZGoAxYBsW81DK3RiHnXMAAr9T3vUNuFRb9@jvqme/o@6mg@tN37UNhHICw5yBpIhHp7B/9MUHvWu4UpTMNIBIRMggnOgfB0FC0whI2QhIwgfKgNUD0YgIUMDI6AQhDQ1NIISRqZmYAKowFgHigzByByoAo4A "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online"): `⌽1⊥¨⌽⊂⍨2|⌽(⊥⍨=)¨,\∘⌽`

Comment: i couldn't beat the above but i thought this might be worth sharing: `∊{⍺∊⍵:⊂⍺0+⍵⋄⍺⍵}/⎕,⊂⍬` - a 20 using a completely different approach

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 94 bytes

```python
def f(a,r=[]):
 while a:
    if len(a)>1and a[-1]==a[-2]:a.pop();a[-1]*=2
    r=[a.pop()]+r
 print r
```

[**Try it online**](https://repl.it/DpVo)

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), <s>73</s> 82 Bytes

```julia
f(l)=l==[]?[]:foldr((x,y)->y[]==x?vcat(2x,y[2:end]):vcat(x,y),[l[end]],l[1:end-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDRisMgEEXf/YqBfVEwUG2ahoDpc79hmIeybSCL2CV1l/brs6OmIaxcBzn3Xgb8@vHjpZnnQXrlvHNIJ6RuuPvrJOVTv1TVv5Cce55@Py9RWkZou1u4kuoySRmNHhMi7dEkszKk5nh7xAc4QHEOEUl/QNUDkkCrgVWz3pDf7WosXkKLXUj7L2Q37ZqNUrIluLHbDE2TkECzs5wq82DsMuyhyWPduKvbTYp7ew1FJuvIfNW7xW6Tlx1TN10SJMRwnyDCGCD/iAA@39MYog8yguthkFEpwd82/wE)

Use right fold to build list from back to front (one could also use fold left and reverse the list at the beginning and end).

If the head of the current list is not equal to the next element to prepend, then just prepend it.

Else remove the head of the list (sounds kind of cruel) and prepend the element times 2.

*Example*

```julia
f([3,3,3,1,1,7,5,5,5,5]) 
returns a new list:
[3,6,2,7,10,10]
```

Comment: `[1024,1024,512,512,256,256]` returns `[2048,512,1024]` instead of `[2048,1024,512]`

Answer (score 2):

### Racket 166 bytes

```
(λ(l)(let g((l(reverse l))(o '()))(cond[(null? l)o][(=(length l)1)(cons(car l)o)]
[(=(car l)(second l))(g(drop l 2)(cons(* 2(car l))o))][(g(cdr l)(cons(car l)o))])))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define f
  (λ (lst)
    (let loop ((lst (reverse lst)) 
               (nl '()))
      (cond                            ; conditions: 
        [(null? lst)                   ; original list empty, return new list;
               nl]
        [(= (length lst) 1)            ; single item left, add it to new list
              (cons (first lst) nl)]
        [(= (first lst) (second lst))  ; first & second items equal, add double to new list
              (loop (drop lst 2) 
                    (cons (* 2 (first lst)) nl))]
        [else                          ; else just move first item to new list
              (loop (drop lst 1) 
                    (cons (first lst) nl))]  
        ))))
```

Testing:

```
(f '[])
(f '[2 2 4 4]) 
(f '[2 2 2 4 4 8]) 
(f '[2 2 2 2]) 
(f '[4 4 2 8 8 2])
(f '[1024 1024 512 512 256 256]) 
(f '[3 3 3 1 1 7 5 5 5 5])
(f '[3 3 3 1 1 7 5 5 5 5 5])
```

Output:

```
'()
'(4 8)
'(2 4 8 8)
'(4 4)
'(8 2 16 2)
'(2048 1024 512)
'(3 6 2 7 10 10)
'(3 6 2 7 5 10 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 51 bytes

```
Abs[#//.{Longest@a___,x_/;x>0,x_,b___}:>{a,-2x,b}]&
```

---

`{Longest@a___,x_/;x>0,x_,b___}` matches a list containing two consecutive identical positive numbers and transform these two numbers into `-2x`. `Longest` forces the matches to happen as late as possible.

The process is illustrated step by step:

```
   {3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5}
-> {3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 7, 5, 5, -10}
-> {3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 7, -10, -10}
-> {3, 3, 3, -2, 7, -10, -10}
-> {3, -6, -2, 7, -10, -10}
-> {3, 6, 2, 7, 10, 10}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 12 bytes

```
ò¦ ®ò2n)mxÃc
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=8qYgrvIybilteMNj&input=LW1RClsKICBbXSwKICBbMiwgMiwgNCwgNF0sCiAgWzIsIDIsIDIsIDQsIDQsIDhdLAogIFsyLCAyLCAyLCAyXSwKICBbNCwgNCwgMiwgOCwgOCwgMl0sCiAgWzEwMjQsIDEwMjQsIDUxMiwgNTEyLCAyNTYsIDI1Nl0sCiAgWzMsIDMsIDMsIDEsIDEsIDcsIDUsIDUsIDUsIDVdCl0=)

#### Unpacked & How it works

```
Uò!= mZ{Zò2n)mx} c

Uò!=    Partition the input array where two adjacent values are different
        i.e. Split into arrays of equal values
mZ{     Map the following function...
Zò2n)     Split into arrays of length 2, counting from the end
          e.g. [2,2,2,2,2] => [[2], [2,2], [2,2]]
mx        Map `Array.sum` over it
}
c       Flatten the result
```

Got some idea from [Jonathan Allan's Jelly solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95413/78410).

Comment: [10 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=8qYgY1/yINRteA&input=WzIsMiwyLDQsNCw4XQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Common Lisp](http://www.clisp.org/), 143 bytes

```lisp
(defun e(l)(if(<(length l)1)'()(if(eq(car l)(cadr l))(cons(*(car l)2)(e(cddr l)))(cons(car l)(e(cdr l))))))
(defun f(l)(reverse(e(reverse l))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU/BDsIgDL37Fc0SY/EkuOkO/syygS5BNmF63K/PFvDgMl5Ky3sPWlrbh3FZsNPm7UCjFdgbvKHV7j49wAopDhg5/cK28cRQ6jhTMbiAx0wrgRrbLklZyxeYTzStXe5luJfXH@2DJkeukus3z@h7h0EAmsE/mwkmKOZm3hcQ@B1WSQIa8P@oQEEJ5QYbeag3FbVi2amgJqwVeVIlxK2SKoaqLhwr3xkYknCFKoE/9wU)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>100</s> <s>73</s> 71 bytes

Thanks to @jo-king -27 bytes! and @jakque -2 bytes

```python
n=lambda l:l[1:]and[*n(l[:~(l[-1]==l[-2])]),l[-1]*-~(l[-1]==l[-2])]or l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBBCsMgEEX3PcUsYzAQTdMGwRv0BjKLlLQ0YE1I3HTTq9uJJoG28viDz2FQx5d/DK4Kl372t1mbA9AyyFOVHIgj8W1WyaH583IzqYFME9m9KCX5lLWQa8j6FGPrqjgkRORMbTuIwWnbPq9dC1ZZIxS2rjO5y6xRb4pCoNZUJDJkPO7z4vdgmMCG@5LL06F3kP5AxQuMU@98RhMXx1j4AA)

Comment: 71 bytes :[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBBCsMgEEX3PcUsYzAQTdMGwRv0BjKLlLQ0YE1I3HTTq9uJJoG28viDz2FQx5d/DK4Kl372t1mbA9AyyFOVHIgj8W1WyaH583IzqYFME9m9KCX5lLWQa8j6FGPrqjgkRORMbTuIwWnbPq9dC1ZZIxS2rjO5y6xRb4pCoNZUJDJkPO7z4vdgmMCG@5LL06F3kP5AxQuMU@98RhMXx1j4AA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 34 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous prefix lambda.

```apl
{∊((⊃⍴⍨2|≢),+⍨⍴⍨∘⌊2÷⍨≢)¨⍵⊂⍨2≠/0,⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pRR5eGRp1RzaPORZqP2iY/6mrW0X7Uu@JR7xYQ2THjUU@X0eHtIDZQwSGg@NZHXU1ArtGjzgX6BjpAfu3/tEdtEx719j3qm@rpDzTg0HrjR20TgbzgIGcgGeLhGfw/TeFR7xquNAUjHRAyASI4B8rXUbBAFjICciDCQI4FGIGEDA2MgEIQ0tTQCEoYmZqBCaACYx0oMgQjc6AKOAIA)

`{`…`}` dfn; `⍵` is right argument

`0,⍵` prepend a zero to the argument

`2≠/` pairwise inequality mask

`⍵⊂⍨` use that to partition (true means begin new partition here) the argument

`(`…`)¨` apply the following tacit function to each run of equal numbers:

`≢` the length of the run

`2÷⍨` let 2 divide that

`⌊` floor that

`∘` then

`⍴⍨` use it to **r**eshape…

`+⍨` the doubled (lit. addition selfie) run

`(`…`),` append that to the following:

`≢` the length of the run

`2|` division remainder when divided by two (1 for odd length runs, 0 for even length runs)

`⊃⍴⍨` use that to reshape the first element of the run

`∊` **e**nlist (flatten)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>8</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
γ2δôOí˜
```

-1 byte thanks to *@ovs*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3Gajc1sOb/E/vPb0nP//o010THSMdCyA0CgWAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXL/3Objc5tObzF//Da03P@6/yPjo7VUYg20gFCGMNExwQuBuLoWCC4YEUgMSMdCyAEcw0NjEx0wISpoREYG5magTBI0lgHBA2B0FzHFAJRjQAZEgsA).

**Explanation:**

```python
γ        # Split the (implicit) input into chunks of equal adjacent values
         #  i.e. [4,4,2,8,8,8,2] → [[4,4],[2],[8,8,8],[2]]
  δ      # Map each to:
 2 ô     #  Split it into parts of size 2
         #   → [[[4,4]],[[2]],[[8,8],[8]],[[2]]]
    O    # Take the sum of each
         #  → [[8],[2],[16,8],[2]]
     í   # Reverse each
         #  → [[8],[2],[8,16],[2]]
      ˜  # Flatten everything
         #  → [8,2,8,16,2]
         # (after which the resulting list is output implicitly)
```

Comment: [`γ2δôOí˜`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3Gajc1sOb/E/vPb0nP//o010THSMdCyA0CgWAA) for 7 bytes. The last two bytes could be `€\`` as well

Comment: @ovs Thanks. Looks like this one was one my earlier 05AB1E answers where I forgot about `δ`. :) Nice alternative with ``€` ``, though.

Comment: @ovs Out of curiosity: how do you put a trailing tilde inside a codeblock within a comment? I know it's possible to have it inside a string with double tildes (i.e. assuming these single quotes are tildes: `''like'this''` -> ``like`this``), but I'm not sure with a leading/trailing tilde. Are you using an unprintable character or something, or you know a way where `<code></code>` works in comments?

Comment: You can escape `\`` with a backslash, the source of the above is `\`€\\`\`` (<- this needs even more backslashes ;) ). BTW my computer tells me `\`` is a *grave accent*, a tilde is `~`.

Comment: @ovs Ah, I mixed up tilde and grave accent indeed, mb. And thanks, didn't even knew you could escape them. Makes sense I guess.

Answer (score 1):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 7 bytes

```
ĉ~ĭ+↔aj
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FquPdNYdWav9qG1KYtaS4qTkYqj4gpsp0bFc0UY6RjomOiZQFpitYwHnGQFZIBEjHQsgBPEMDYxMdMCEqaERGBuZmoEwUM5YBwQNgdBcxxQCYyGWAQA)

A port of [@The Thonnu's Thunno 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/261231/9288).

```
ĉ~ĭ+↔aj
ĉ           Split the input into runs of identical items
 ~   a      For each run:
  ĭ             Deinterleave
   +            Add
    ↔           Reverse
      j     Concatenate
```

Answer (score 0):

### Java 8, <s>130</s> 114 bytes

**Edit:**

- ***-16** bytes off. Thanks to @Kevin Cruijssen.*

Snipet:

```
s->{int j=0,i=s.length,l[]=new int[i];for(;--i>-1;[j++]=s[i]==s[i-1]?s[i--]*2:s[i]);return Collection.reverse(l);}
```

Code:

```
public static int[] shift(int[]a){
  List<int> out = new ArrayList<>();
  for(int i = s.length-1; i>-1;i--){
    if(s[i]==s[i-1]){
      out.add(s[i]*2);
      i--;
    }else{
      out.add(s[i]);
    }
  }
  return Arrays.reverse(out.toArray());
}
```

Comment: Hi, you can golf it some more like this: `s->{int j=0,i=s.length,l[]=new int[i];for(;--i>-1;[j++]=s[i]==s[i-1]?s[i--]*2:s[i]);...}` Also, `Arrays#reverse` doesn't exist?.. :S `Collections#reverse` does, but Arrays not a.f.a.i.k. (And if it did exist, you'd need `java.util.` in front of it.)

Comment: This code is not fully representational of the full code required to run it, nor is it capable of running as-is.

Comment: I wrote `Snipet` not `full programm` and this declares a function object as the OP said: `The task is to write a function [...]`

Comment: I can't get either version of your code to compile in Java 8. Additionally, it looks to me like your golfed code returns an array of the original size, not the newly modified size.

Answer (score 0):

## Vim, 28 bytes

`G@='?\v(\d+)\n\1<C-@>DJ@"<C-A>-@=<C-@>'<CR>`

A macro that regex searches backward for matching consecutive numbers, and adds them together.

**The input array needs to be one number per line.** This format saves me strokes, which is nice, but the real reason is to work around overlapping regex matches. Given the string `222`, if you `/22` you'll match only the first pair, not the overlapping second pair. The overlap rules are different when the two pairs start on different lines. In this challenge `[2, 2, 2]` becomes `[2, 4]`, so matching the overlapping pair is critical.

**NOTE:** The challenge asked for only a single pass. For that reason, you need to have `:set nowrapscan`. With `:set wrapscan` I could make a version that finishes the job on multiple passes, though this solution as written won't always do that.

- `<C-@>`: Normally, in a command line, to type a literal `<CR>` without running the command you'd have to escape it with `<C-V>`. But you can type `<C-@>` unescaped and it will be treated as a `<C-J>`/`<NL>`, which will be like `<CR>` when you run the macro but not when you're typing. Try reading `:help NL-used-for-Nul`.
- `@=`: I can't use a recorded macro easily this time because there's a possibility the input might have no matching pairs. If that happens while running a macro, the unsuccessful search will fail the macro. But if it happens during the (implicit first) recording pass, the rest of the normal mode commands will run, damaging the file. The downside of `@=` is I lose a byte on the recursive call; sometimes you can use `@@` as a recursive call, but that would run `@"` from 4 bytes earlier in this case.
- `DJ@"<C-A>-`: `DJ` deletes the line and puts the number (no newline) in a register, so I can run it as a macro for a number argument to `<C-A>`. I have to `-` afterward so I don't get a second match in cases like `[4, 2, 2]`.

Answer (score 0):

### Perl6, 92 bytes

```
{my @b;loop ($_=@^a-1;$_>=0;--$_) {@b.unshift($_&&@a[$_]==@a[$_-1]??2*@a[$_--]!!@a[$_])};@b}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), <s>97</s> 87 bytes

```
[N,N|T]+[O|Q]:-O is N*2,T+Q.
[N|T]+[N|Q]:-T+Q.
R+R.
L-R:-reverse(L,M),M+Q,reverse(Q,R).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYu9CoMwFIV3n@KO2txITf/EpS@gkQS34BiKILXEUhffPU0T26GI8HGG853zMEM/3Og4ddYqjnxuWqLqWbQFraEbge8YNkSkkQqKe@UbSWQalVQW1OiXNqOOS6wSrIjAbyFQJqm9UlAtlQiT6Z66v8eujD4lQ3AcHRt6WSDk2yO2qsPV6dyzPsr2zI1CnjK2BDudfaxeDgiBzHNxnx//B/sG)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 55 bytes

```ruby
->a{c=[];c=[(b=a.pop)==a[-1]?a.pop*2:b]+c while a[0];c}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6xOtk2OtYaSGgk2SbqFeQXaNraJkbrGsbag3laRlZJsdrJCuUZmTmpConRBkC1tf8LFNKiow11jHSMY2O5EBwgNNEx1TEDQnMdCx1LEIQpMAEqgGAQaQQjY2P/AwA)

So long and still no Ruby answer? It can't be.

More golfing will follow.

Answer (score 0):

## C (GCC), 87 bytes

I'm not very familiar with the allowed I/O methods for C, but I think this is valid. The function takes an input array `a` (`int *`) and length `l` and two empty parameters `r` and `w` (`int`). The output is stored to the right portion of the input array, and the new length is returned.

```c
f(a,l,r,w)int*a;{for(r=w=l;r--;)a[--w]=r<1|a[r]-a[r-1]?a[r]:a[r--]*2;return!!~l*~w-~l;}
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##bVJtb5swEP4Mv@KSaSqk9gaszaoRuh9CEUK8tJaoqQws0jLy17M720C0RTqd787Pcy/2lfy1LC@XxitYyxQ7@kIOuyI@NZ3yVHJM2lhxHvtFyvkxS9Qh/FOkKuOoeJj9JPsH2TzbRbGqh1HJzebc7s5Hfm7j6eK6n4Qs27Gq4dAPlei@vD277q9OVPChsFReKOXhCWnGoBe/63zwY3OvRpmXRV//f32Lj@eK0YcPJ9f5GIfyrVDeXXqHRMdeCzRxQPAEJBDEIOCgKWTdJxBqqqMLNN72c7VlOr/IKIcjGiJuEk0BPsMXPIOtxk0uydJBRh1M7o3hhETQze6vRkSIAVDuuRTwZ1OM0nTjkOuWEmiuCQwClIW25oN78OwMM9dnqxlfNf8ibfdU6L0Q0qMxdJMUoVH6NEvDIMPq9BqnYGJ0RAxQHlCufRti8PRPNDK@uUT/SYuNhkGEUaMfw8iq6HGvlcF8Y2Ak1PIdQYsQYrKPRRNix9RtoIvtZ72nEghznVH24lXWFcwj5rKbN8e6Zn9mx2xR15js8HV26Zf9Fbau2LIG5gEtwG7C6tNXTPj6l78)

The program may read at index -1 in the input array, which seems to work fine in my test program. Valgrind reports this access in some cases, but I was unable to get this to crash the program with global, automatic, or `malloc`ed input arrays on my system.

### Acknowledgments

- -6 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell, <s>73</s> 71 bytes

```powershell
for($r=@();$z=$args[--$i]){$i-=$e=$z-eq$args[$i-1]
$r=,($z+$z*$e)+$r}$r
```

Less golfed test script:

```powershell
$f = {

$r=@()                      # result
for(;$z=$args[--$i]){       # all elements from end to start
    $e=$z-eq$args[$i-1]     # current is $equal to previous
    $i-=$e                  # shift if need 
    $r=,($z+$z*$e)+$r       # insert to start
}
$r                          # output result

}

@(
    ,( @()  ,  @() )
    ,( (2, 2, 4, 4)  , (4, 8) )
    ,( (2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 8)  , (2, 4, 8, 8) )
    ,( (2, 2, 2, 2)  , (4, 4) )
    ,( (4, 4, 2, 8, 8, 2)  , (8, 2, 16, 2) )
    ,( (1024, 1024, 512, 512, 256, 256)  , (2048, 1024, 512) )
    ,( (3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5)  , (3, 6, 2, 7, 10, 10) )
) | % {
    $arr,$expected = $_
    $result = &$f @arr     # splatting
    "$("$result"-eq"$expected"): $result"
}
```

Output:

```powershell
True:
True: 4 8
True: 2 4 8 8
True: 4 4
True: 8 2 16 2
True: 2048 1024 512
True: 3 6 2 7 10 10
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 18 bytes

```
$L1=?v;2d=?+;v;O@_
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/1/Fx9DWvszaKMXWXtu6zNrfIf7////RxjoKEGQIRuY6CqZwFAsA)**

```
$                     \ While there are items left on input stack:
 L1=?                 \  if len(input) == 1:
     v;               \    move the final remaining item to output stack
                      \  else:
       2d             \    copy the last two items
         =?           \    if equal:
           +;         \      add together
             v;       \    move the last item on stack to output stack
               O@_    \ Print the output stack (reversed)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org) 5.3, <del>117</del> 113 bytes

```lua
function f(t)i,o=#t,{}while i>0 do v=t[i]if v==t[i-1]then v=v*2i=i-1 end i=i-1table.insert(o,1,v)end return o end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVBBasMwEDzHr1jci1UUY6lJm4vzkWCK6khkwUhBlt2D8dvdlRRKWwrDMDM7i1gNk9o2M9k@oLNgqsCQu/Yp8GX9vOGgAc8NXB3Mbbhgh4ZEVHvRhZu25OZniS150PYKSQX1Mega7ah9qBwXfGZx5nWYvAUXi5txHt459GqkFyzcFfpxKXbLyomaxJID4UD4YR8Jh9PvUCabR2RPCTkUjaQw81HIB8nja6JUeeGQIRLeqPMNKqz0AcXu7tGGqrxACXUN@cje2V6FKp7BoSSwOCuhixr255T9t2HSDvuzxAr6m2L7Ag)

I think Lua 5.1 would require an extra byte because a number has to be separated from an identifier: `v=v*2i=i-1` → `v=v*2 i=i-1`.

Comment: [113 bytes](https://tio.run/##bVBBasMwEDzHr1jci1UUY6lJm4vzkWCK6khkwUhBlt2D8dvdlRRKWwrDMDM7i1gNk9o2M9k@oLNgqsCQu/Yp8GX9vOGgAc8NXB3Mbbhgh4ZEVHvRhZu25OZniS150PYKSQX1Mega7ah9qBwXfGZx5nWYvAUXi5txHt459GqkFyzcFfpxKXbLyomaxJID4UD4YR8Jh9PvUCabR2RPCTkUjaQw81HIB8nja6JUeeGQIRLeqPMNKqz0AcXu7tGGqrxACXUN@cje2V6FKp7BoSSwOCuhixr255T9t2HSDvuzxAr6m2L7Ag) through some rearranging

Comment: Excellent! Updated post.

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 72 bytes

```cs
x=>{for(int i=x.Count-1;i>0;)if(x[i--]==x[i]){x.RemoveAt(i);x[i--]*=2;}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU@xCoMwEN39ioxJidIGByFGkK4dSukmDiKRHrQJaGoFybfbi6VDi9xw99473t1rh7gdYClbB9bkJxhcDsYVBemIWiZVzJ3tKTIE1JQc7dO4@CCh2EsGHZ0qiONaKew1m6fkoh921KWjwORH2ykhvV9khDa6aW90bHri9IB@hhj9quo5ImFA7BB4/gMFFzzl6Qa78jzbVMQfGzYFz7CE9ywKF8MbdwxL1PpNcrUhOmUStY4GZR3PPTp8oV/e)

This function [outputs by modifying an argument](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4942/8340).

Credit to @ASCIIOnly for suggesting that I *not* create a new list. That suggestion led me to discover the above referenced rule. Total savings of 22 bytes without creating a new list and by removing the return statement :)

Less golfed...

```cs
// x is an input List
x=>{
  // iterate from back to front
  for(int i=x.Count-1;i>0;)
    // check for consecutive elements
    if(x[i--]==x[i]){
      // remove the first occurrence
      x.RemoveAt(i);
      // double the second occurrence
      // which has been shifted
      x[i--]*=2;
    }
}
```

Comment: [why not this](https://tio.run/##jY0xC8IwFIR3f0XGRJKioUMhTaAITg4ibqVTSeANJpCmGij97TFVEATBcsM73n3c9QPrB0jH0fb1CYZQgw2KfpxCBskUpZqM8zh/EMhYHNxoA9sLUDtBwODYAmOdlPl2ZIrFRd/cXTcBAxHvbCu5mL0Oo7coijmJzdnnNmyw1Q@UXdtNc3F1yzAmhPzKOeW0pOUa7AXSah3K/2FLF6dV1jeang)

Comment: I see... You are forcing the type to be a proper `List` vs `IList`. It seemed a little strange to be mangling the input and returning the same object, but I guess that doesn't matter as much w/ code golf :) Almost seems like you'd want to use `Action<List>` and don't return anything?

Comment: Well... they _do_ say "returns a shifted array". Plus, solutions of many languages _are_ modifying the array simply because it is so insanely expensive to duplicate it

Comment: @ASCIIOnly - looks like modifying the input might suffice. https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4942/8340

Comment: Oh, huh, TIL. I guess it's just that it's not too often that modifying input is shorter

Comment: Yeah - I'm still pretty green here :) Lots of rules to learn, but at least there seems to be a pretty history to see what's been decided upon in the past.

Answer (score 0):

## [F# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 87 bytes

```fs
fun x->(List.foldBack(fun e (h::t)->if h=e then 0::e*2::t.Tail else e::e::t)x [0]).Tail
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcsxC4MwEIbhvb/iEApJISLBQRIU2rljN3EQe4ehIRaTgv8@TZyV297nO/JiWlaMFgNQyyL9HGyiY0/jQ0mLfT/G6cNyRWCzUoGLzhDMLUKY0UGlFN5k6uVrNBbQegRMLS836KuB7xD55bsaF8hBcb0XwAj64aBJLXWt6zPaUTfnLI8o/0jdpEsc/w)

Uses the `List.foldBack` function to process the input from back to front. The head of the working list contains an element that can be merged, or a `0` to indicate the previous element cannot be merged

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
ṁȯ↔mΣC2g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOxhPrH7VNyT232Nko/f///9FGOiBoAoQWsQA)

`ṁ` is a lifesaver here.

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 69 bytes

```julia
x\y=x!==y[1] ? Int[x;y] : [2.0x;[y;][2:end]]
!l=l>[] ? foldr(\,l) : l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDbasMwDH3XVyjspYVsxF6ahgZnz/sGVQ@DtpBh3JF64Hx9JttpCDPHB3EuCPT9a4cvFeY5nCcTCmMmUowf@Ok8hW5iPCHptyp0NHVM@nR1F2YorLE9xdztbi/j7lzavSTt7K8P/0CDBMTlC772SAykSxTUgqcoc7saixelxc5K@y@kN@1ajFzSObix2ySqJkpAqtKSynxQeiF9aBKtG6u63aSk915ihko4ir7i2RK3ScuOsRs/AwPc7iN6HBymcwDK@xkH563beTQ9Fn4PckiY/wA)

when 2 numbers are merged, they are turned into a float, so that it won't be `===` to the next number, which is an integer. When there is no merge, the numbers are converted back to integers to re-allow merging numbers

based on [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95459/98541) answer

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 61 bytes

```julia
x\y=x!==y[]?Int[x;y]:[2.0x;[y;][2:end]]
!l=l!=[]?foldr(\,l):l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDbCoJAEH2frxjppcBCNzNRtp77hmkeggqMZQvbQL/exl0TaTl7GM6FgXl8TH3J@749d7qNtO6IjyfrqK06LkltkrairmJS5c1emSEy2kRaQvenuTbLc2xWpend7e3eqJGAOF7g@oDEQCpGQSb4iTIXkzF6gzTaQSn@QmrWzsQIJRWCM7vwYpoPElCaKEkF3qVqJLXLPU0bk6yYpaS3jTEg9diLPuHXEjf3y/ZDd/gMDHB/NuiwtujPASjv1dTWGbt0qA8YuRXIFaH/Ag)

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), <s>114</s> 112 bytes

```java
n->{List l=new Stack();for(int i=n.length;i-->1;)if(n[i]>0)l.add(n[i]==n[i-1]?n[i]*2+(n[i-1]=0):n[i]);return l;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVDBboMwDL3zFT6SbqQFbTssg2nHStupx6qHFAJNmyYoMZ2qim9nCbQshxc9@9l@9pFfeHKsToM8t8YiHD2nHUpFFyyKSsWdgx8uNdyiCPxbLqE8cN0IvlcCpEZha16KMTczWHs53N@3dPix9qlG2AJQOITYK7c7r287JGxU9lP7ttsrWYJDjv67GFnBOUyPN2ilbnwRt40jDzd3R05g186BNTij/ApGQz4H/9WNUbWooDSVGHRS3II/ULkWv7BBXp5iwmpjg0WQuaZK6AYPTCZJkTIi61hv5a5YEUV5VY0kzz0m6e4zkEX2FE80X5H3ECHMentWg2L94G86W5qOEA7yZS2/Qg63dJW9PMOEr2l2h@z1bYSezbWbq0NxpqZD2vrDoNLxY2kaOsZzW0IeM/uoH/4A)

Returns the list in reverse.
-2 Thanks to celingcat.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
òÎc_ò Ômx
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=8s5jX/Ig1G14&input=WzMgMyAzIDEgMSA3IDUgNSA1IDVdCi1R) or [run all test cases](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=8s5jX/Ig1G14&input=WwpbXQpbMiAyIDQgNF0KWzIgMiAyIDQgNCA4XQpbMiAyIDIgMl0KWzQgNCAyIDggOCAyXQpbMTAyNCAxMDI0IDUxMiA1MTIgMjU2IDI1Nl0KWzMgMyAzIDEgMSA3IDUgNSA1IDVdCl0tbVI)

```
òÎc_ò Ômx     :Implicit input of array
ò             :Partition between elements where
 Î            :  The sign of their difference is truthy (not 0)
  c           :Map then flatten
   _          :By passing each array through the following function
    ò         :  Partitions of length 2
      Ô       :  Reverse
       m      :  Map
        x     :    Reduce by addition
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 57 bytes

```arturo
$=>[chunk&=>[&]|map=>[map&++0[x y]->x+y|reverse]|flatten]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?WfKyEc)

```
$=>[                     ; a function where input is assigned to &
    chunk&=>[&]          ; split input into lists of equal contiguous elements
    |map=>[              ; then map each list to...
        map              ; map over...
        &++0             ; ...input list with 0 appended
        [x y]->          ; in pairs; assign elements to x and y
            x+y          ; add the pair
        |reverse         ; then reverse the list
    ]                    ; end map
    |flatten             ; then flatten the result
]                        ; end function
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `S`, 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ġı2ẇʂr
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0UrBS7IKlpSVpuharjyw8stHo4a72U01FS4qTkouh4gs2RRvpKECQCRhZxEJkAA)

Inspired by Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer.

##### Explanation

```python
ġı2ẇʂr  # Implicit input              [2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 8]
ġ       # Group consecutive items     [[2, 2, 2], [4, 4], [8]]
 ı      # Map:                        [2, 2, 2]       [4, 4]     [8]
  2ẇ    #  Split into pairs           [[2, 2], [2]]   [[4, 4]]   [[8]]
    ʂ   #  Sum each inner list        [4, 2]          [8]        [8]
     r  #  Reverse                    [2, 4]          [8]        [8]
        # End map                     [[2, 4], [8], [8]]
        # Implicit output, flattened  [2, 4, 8, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `d`, 43 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 5.375 bytes

```
Ġƛy+ṘC
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJkPSIsIiIsIsSgxpt5K+G5mEMiLCIiLCJbMiwgMiwgMiwgNCwgNCwgOF0iXQ==)

Outputs as characters representing each value, as [in this meta consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18027/78850).

*-5 bits thanks to @alephalpha*

### Explained

```
Ġƛy+ṘC­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‏​⁢⁠⁡‌­
Ġƛ      # ‎⁡To each consecutive group of values:
  y+    # ‎⁢  Uninterleave the group and add the two halves
    Ṙ   # ‎⁣  Reverse
     C  # ‎⁤  Convert to character
# ‎⁢⁡The d flag flattens then sums the result


 Created with the help of Luminespire at https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire
```

Comment: - ½ byte: `2ẇṠ` -> `y+`